# Hide complete background for an image with css

Tags: css

We have image displaying like below :

[image]

Once we mouse-click on image, it add some background color like below :

[image]

but we want to **remove that background - color**.

**html**

```
<label for="options_455_3" class="colors" style="background-image: 

url(&quot;http://1234.com/media/catalog/custom/blue.png&quot;);">Blue </label>
```

**css**

```
.product-options ul.options-list .label>label.colors {
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    border-radius: 50%; 
    background-size: cover !important;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 !important;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

I removed this code : `border-radius: 50%;` so now still its displaying little bit background in right side of image as below . But I want to hide that one also.

Here is [Site link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/yang-yin.html)

[image]

I tried other codes like `border: 0 !important;` but nothing worked for me. please help me with only css code.

Comment: Why use a image? You can use a div and make it rounded, it's much easier to play with.

Comment: @Troyer we need to display different different color images for different pages, so we used images....

Comment: You can use diferent css clases to swap the color :)

Comment: width: 43px;
height: 43px;
border-radius: 0%;

Seems to do the trick..

Comment: can you provide js fiddle

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time @Troyer , i will try to follow as you said once i complete current tasks.....

Comment: @al27091 Thanks for your valuable time , but we want the `width & height` to be 38px only....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Following css remove background when you click on your image.

```
.product-options input[type="radio"]:checked + span, input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:hover, .product-options input[type="radio"]:checked + span, input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:focus,.product-options input[type="radio"]:checked + span, input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:active

{

background:transparent !important;
box-shadow:none !important;
}
```

Comment: can you please help me to remove `background/border` covering that image , when i used `.options-list .label {
    border: 0 !important;
}` its hiding `border` for above sizes too [ L , XL, XXL ..etc.... ]

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is actually coming from the CSS of `<span>` parent of that label and not the label itself.

```
<span class="label"><!-- This tag-->
    <label for="options_453_3" class="colors" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://stylebaby.com/media/catalog/custom/blue.png&quot;);">Blue </label>
</span>
```

Set `width: 40px;` in the label class used on the above `<span>` or give it a new class with `width: 40px;` and the white space will be removed.

Comment: you are using &quot; instead of '

Comment: is it correct,  background-image: url(&quot;http://stylebaby.com/media/catalog/custom/blue.png&quot;);

Comment: Oh now I understand what you mean that is just what happens when copying and pasting code from console.

Comment: Thanks @Callum , your answer worked fine.... but as other user gave answer first ,  accepted that one.....

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the background colour #e0e0e0 is specified twice in one of your style sheets. I have copied the culprits below. I have commented them out

**Line 8720**

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1224px)
.product-options input[type=radio]:checked + span, input[type=checkbox]:checked + span {
    background-image: none;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    background-color: #e0e0e0; 
}
```

**Line 9281**

```
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1824px)
    .product-options input[type=radio]:checked + span, input[type=checkbox]:checked + span {
        background-image: none;
        outline: 0;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
        box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
         background-color: #e0e0e0; 
    }
```

Comment: thanks for support..... now its working fine , as other user gave answer first , accepted that one.....